# Coredata app in semaphore_wait_trap situation

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I am maintaining an iPad CoreData application for iOS 9.3 and having lot of freezing problems.

The app uses  threading and works fine with iOS 8.2 (and also with iOS10beta!)
Thread 16 is blocking thread 1

I wonder what and why this  is happening and if  there is a work around?

Any help is welcome.

```
- (void)postRequestDoneNotification
{
    // Perform one save to rule them all...
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [[KKPDataManager sharedManager] saveContext:self.backgroundContext andWriteToDisk:YES withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

        __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (strongSelf) {
            // Post notifications for objects done changing
            if (strongSelf.updatedAnimals && ([strongSelf.updatedAnimals count]>0)) {
                [strongSelf.updatedAnimals enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                    [strongSelf performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sendAnimalDidChangeNotification:) withObject:obj waitUntilDone:NO];
                }];
            }

            // Notify any observers
            [strongSelf performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sendKKPServerRequestDoneNotification:) withObject:kNSNotificationKKPAnimalRequestDone waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }];
}



- (void)saveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context andWriteToDisk:(BOOL)writeToDisk withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionBlock
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    if (context == self.writerManagedObjectContext) {

        if (writeToDisk) {
            [context performBlockAndWait:^{
                [weakSelf saveContext:context andWait:YES withCompletionHandler:completionBlock];
            }];
        }

    } else {

        void (^saveContextBlock) () = ^{

            // Save MOC and push changes up one level.
            [weakSelf saveContext:context andWait:YES withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
                if (!strongSelf) {
                    [LogUtil logWithSeverity:LogLevelError messageWithFormat:@"KKPDataManager instance was removed! Cannot save context."];
                } else if (!error) {

                    if (writeToDisk && context.parentContext) {
                        // Continue saving parent contexts until the writer MOC has been reached
                        [strongSelf saveContext:context.parentContext andWriteToDisk:writeToDisk withCompletionHandler:completionBlock];
                    }

                } else {

                    // Don't forget to execute the completion block!
                    if (completionBlock) {
                        completionBlock(error);

                    } else if (error) {

                        // No completion block; just send any errors to the log
                        NSMutableString *logMessage = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@.", [error localizedDescription]];
                        NSError *underlyingError = [error.userInfo valueForKey:NSUnderlyingErrorKey];
                        if (underlyingError)
                            [logMessage appendFormat:@" Underlying error: %@ - %@", [underlyingError localizedDescription], [underlyingError userInfo]];
                        [LogUtil logWithSeverity:LogLevelError messageWithFormat:@"%@.", logMessage];
                    }
                }
            }];
        };

        [context performBlockAndWait:saveContextBlock];
    }
}
```

This is the backtrace

```
    * thread #1: tid = 0x485828, 0x04c504d6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x04c504d6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x048d808c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait + 25
    frame #2: 0x048d0415 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 480
    frame #3: 0x048d0224 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 88
    frame #4: 0x0336cbd2 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 242
    frame #5: 0x002104ca KKP-iPad`-[KKPDataManager saveContext:andWriteToDisk:withCompletionHandler:](self=0x7bf286e0, _cmd="saveContext:andWriteToDisk:withCompletionHandler:", context=0x7df07040, writeToDisk=YES, completionBlock=0xbff538f8) + 682 at KKPDataManager.m:322
    frame #6: 0x00102270 KKP-iPad`-[RequestAnimal postRequestDoneNotification](self=0x7de0df40, _cmd="postRequestDoneNotification") + 272 at RequestAnimal.m:1340
    frame #7: 0x036b3059 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    frame #8: 0x02f0d5f8 Foundation`__NSThreadPerformPerform + 323
    frame #9: 0x03b1de5f CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    frame #10: 0x03b13aeb CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
    frame #11: 0x03b12f08 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1032
    frame #12: 0x03b12846 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    frame #13: 0x03b1265b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #14: 0x0660a664 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
    frame #15: 0x0660a4a1 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #16: 0x01986eb9 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 160
    frame #17: 0x000c5baa KKP-iPad`main(argc=1, argv=0xbff548b8) + 138 at main.m:14
    frame #18: 0x04918a25 libdyld.dylib`start + 1

  thread #2: tid = 0x485847, 0x04c587de libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager'
    frame #0: 0x04c587de libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10
    frame #1: 0x048dc034 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 257
    frame #2: 0x048dbd84 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread + 60

  thread #6: tid = 0x48585c, 0x04c57d5e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x04c57d5e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x04c1c34b libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1289
    frame #2: 0x04c19f56 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 34

  thread #8: tid = 0x48587a, 0x04c5049a libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10, name = 'com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader'
    frame #0: 0x04c5049a libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x04c4f884 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 68
    frame #2: 0x03b13d16 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 214
    frame #3: 0x03b130f6 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1526
    frame #4: 0x03b12846 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    frame #5: 0x03b1265b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #6: 0x040de036 CFNetwork`+[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 472
    frame #7: 0x02f0feda Foundation`-[NSThread main] + 76
    frame #8: 0x02fc52dc Foundation`__NSThread__start__ + 1346
    frame #9: 0x04c1c780 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 138
    frame #10: 0x04c1c6f6 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 155
    frame #11: 0x04c19f7a libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 34

  thread #9: tid = 0x48588e, 0x04c57726 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 10, name = 'com.apple.CFSocket.private'
    frame #0: 0x04c57726 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 10
    frame #1: 0x03b5d090 CoreFoundation`__CFSocketManager + 912
    frame #2: 0x04c1c780 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 138
    frame #3: 0x04c1c6f6 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 155
    frame #4: 0x04c19f7a libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 34

  thread #16: tid = 0x4859c9, 0x04c504d6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, queue = 'NSManagedObjectContext 0x7df07040'
    frame #0: 0x04c504d6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x048d808c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait + 25
    frame #2: 0x048d0415 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 480
    frame #3: 0x048d0224 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 88
    frame #4: 0x0336d16e CoreData`_perform + 206
    frame #5: 0x0336fefa CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) managedObjectContextDidUnregisterObjectsWithIDs:] + 74
    frame #6: 0x03340816 CoreData`-[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _processReferenceQueue:] + 2054
    frame #7: 0x033f4f1e CoreData`__89-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _registerAyncReferenceCallback]_block_invoke + 126
    frame #8: 0x0336ccfa CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 202
    frame #9: 0x048ee9cd libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #10: 0x048d263c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 2227
    frame #11: 0x048d1af0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 570
    frame #12: 0x048d47a7 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 550
    frame #13: 0x048d457a libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 115
    frame #14: 0x04c1c25c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1050
    frame #15: 0x04c19f56 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 34

  thread #18: tid = 0x485e82, 0x04c57d5e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x04c57d5e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x04c1c34b libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1289
    frame #2: 0x04c19f56 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 34

  thread #17: tid = 0x485e84, 0x04c57d5e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x04c57d5e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x04c1c34b libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1289
    frame #2: 0x04c19f56 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 34

  thread #19: tid = 0x485e89, 0x04c57d5e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x04c57d5e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x04c1c34b libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1289
    frame #2: 0x04c19f56 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 34
```

Comment: Hmm.. any chance we can see some revenant code?

Comment: All the stack trace says is that this happens in `[KKPDataManager saveContext:andWriteToDisk:withCompletionHandler:]` (at `KKPDataManager.m:322`), which was called from `[RequestAnimal postRequestDoneNotification]` (at `RequestAnimal.m:1340`). Look at that code. If you can post that code here, someone might be able to help.

Comment: Hello Florian and @TomHarrington. Thanks for your response. I added the source code of the methods that causes the blocking situation.

Comment: is there ONE writer per thread or do you share anything between threads.. contexts or objects shouldnt be shared depending on concurrency model of MOC .. >> how are the mocs set up